# Making IntelliJ IDEA community edition available in software repository

Tags: software-center, packaging

I'd like to package IntelliJ IDEA (Community) to make it available from the standard Ubuntu software center.

How do I go about this?

Comment: It's Licensed under Apache 2.0 (for Community editions greater than 9.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways you can get an app into USC:

**From Debian:**
If you get your application packaged and accepted into Debian, it will automatically be available in the next release of Ubuntu (depending on when in the development cycle you get it into Debian).  We will also pull the version of your application in Debian into every new release of Ubuntu at the beginning of the development cycle.

**Ubuntu Universe:**
You can also submit your application package directly to Ubuntu's Universe repository.  This is ideal for Ubuntu-specific application that don't make sense for Debian to have, like ubuntu-tweak.  However, if your application isn't Ubuntu-specific, it's preferred that you get it into Debian eventually.

**Ubuntu Developer Portal:**
This is the newest way to get your applications into USC, it supports both open and closed source apps, both free and for sale.  You will need to signup for an account at http://developer.ubuntu.com and follow the guidelines for publishing your app.  Applications submitted this way can be included into any stable supported release of Ubuntu at any time, but they do have slightly different [packaging guidelines](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/my-apps-packages) you will need to follow.